# Adding transparency programmatically using a android color resource

Tags: android

There is a color in `colors.xml` without transparency. I do know that i can add transparency to colors.xml like `#CC666666`. But i need to add this transparency programatically.

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="list_section">#666666</color>
</resource>
```

in my Activity:

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.list_section);
// put transparency here
myView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess bitwise OR could work.
Something like

```
int transparentColor = 0xCC000000 | color;
myView.setBackgroundColor(transparentColor);
```

Comment: You have to mask the alpha to 0x00 before apply transparent 
(color & 0x00FFFFFF) | 0xCC000000